# Not possible to login to approve or reject access to application on Windows Phone 7 device

Tags: bug, stackauth, authentication, windows-phone

I'm making an app for Windows Phone using the Stack Exchange API but I'm having a bit of trouble when I try to let the user approve the application (using client side flow).

I open a web browser at the following URL:

> https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=1464&scope=read_inbox&redirect_uri=https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success

On my PC this displays fine:

[image]

But on the phone I do not see the *You need to login to authorize this application* section.

[image]

This is the same on the emulator and a physical device. Is this a bug? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you have to specifically enable JavaScript for the `WebBrowser` control on Windows Phone.

```
<phone:WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser" IsScriptEnabled="True" />
```